# How can I bind events to dynamically added textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am dynamically creating table rows and adding text boxes.
I added new row and added a event listener to it.
I also tried creating a cell and adding event listener to it.

I am using a Javascript function for this, but my function is invoked even before the
event is triggered from newly created  html element.

In all cases the function is called as soon as dynamic element is created

Any help is appreciated.

Doesn't Work:

*Try 1*

```
function addnewrow()
{
     var row = table.insertRow(x.rowIndex+1);  
     row.addEventListener("click", addme, false); 
}

function addme()
{
     alert("am called "); 
}
```

*Try 2*

```
var t12=document.createElement("input");
t12.id = index+"q";  
t12.name = index+"q";                    
cellnewrow2.appendChild(t12);                
//cellnewrow2.addEventListener("click",addme(),false);  
cellnewrow2.onclick =addme();
```

Comment: Pass function reference i.e. `row.addEventListener("click",addme,false)`, when you use `()` the function is invoked.

Comment: The first example is actually correct and won't call the callback immediately. Can you post a minimal complete example that doesn't work the way you expect it?

Comment: Hi satpal what you told is correct. But i want to pass an argument as well while calling function

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is actually correct. May be there are other ways for your question. But you can also use `bind`and refer your arguments or parameters with `this`keyword inside the function.

```js
function addnewrow() {
  var table = document.getElementById('tbl');
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  row.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";
  let arg = 1;
  row.addEventListener("click", addme.bind(arg));
}

function addme() {
  alert("am called with the argument: " + this);
}

addnewrow();
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't implement a function when you want it to be a callback function.
 With not considering the performance optimizing, it could be the very basic code for you as practice.

```
<html>
<body>
    <button id='btn'>Click Me</button>
    <div id='div'></div>
</body>
<script>
var count = 0;
var btn   = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var div = document.getElementById('div');
    div.innerHTML += '<h2>' + count + '</h2>';
    count++;
});
</script>
</html>
```